# SQL group by each tables and join them

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select home2012.region_name, avg(home2012.per_price), avg(home2019.per_price)
from home2012 left join 
(select region_name, avg(per_price) from home2019 group by region_name) 
on home2012.region_name = home2019.region_name
group by region_name;
```

I want to group by region_name each table(home2012, home2019) and left join them by same region_name(after group by).
But it occurs error.

Comment: You aggregate over `home2019` in a subquery. When you put the subquery in the FROM clause, the name `home2019` is no longer in scope; the name is understood in the subquery, but not in the outer query. Obviously: the result of the subquery is an aggregation, it is not the original table. You must give the subquery an **alias** - and also a column alias to the average price within the subquery - and only reference these aliases in the outer query. This will get you past the current error; likely you will run into new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Make two subselects and join them

```
SELECT
    t2012.region_name, t2012.avgprice2012, t2019.avgprice2019
FROM
    (SELECT 
        home2012.region_name, AVG(home2012.per_price) avgprice2012
    FROM
        home2012
    GROUP BY region_name) AS t2012
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        region_name, AVG(per_price) avgprice2019
    FROM
        home2019
    GROUP BY region_name) AS t2019 ON t2012.region_name = t2019.region_name
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 select 
         home2012.region_name,
         avg(home2012.per_price), 
         avg(home2019.per_price)
    from 
        home2012 
        left join  (select region_name, avg(per_price) from home2019 group by 
                    region_name)  on home2012.region_name = home2019.region_name

    group by region_name;
```

what is the use of joining as mentioned above? does it make any difference rather than increasing one step workload on server.

```
 select 
         home2012.region_name,
         avg(home2012.per_price), 
         avg(home2019.per_price)
    from 
        home2012 
        left join home2019 on home2012.region_name = home2019.region_name

    group by region_name;
```

Comment: I want to join like this!

select home2012.region_name, home2019.region_name, home2012.avg(per_price), home2019.avg(per_price)

from
(select region_name, avg(per_price)
from home2012 
group by region_name) 
join (select region_name, avg(per_price)
from home2019
group by region_name)

on home2012.region_name = home2019.region_name
;

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    name,
    AVG("2012") as "2012",
    AVG("2018") as "2018"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            'region' AS name,
            1 AS "2012",
            NULL AS "2018" // put column as null
        FROM
            dual
  
    UNION
        SELECT
            'region' AS name,
            NULL AS "2012", // put column as null
            avg(3) AS "2018"
        FROM
            dual
            group by 1 
    )
GROUP BY
    name
```

am not sure about your requirement, try something like this.